# Two versions of library dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven

In my `pom.xml` I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20170516</version>
</dependency>
```

And my Program needs and uses this version om JSON.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

When I put in

```
final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
System.out.println( jsonObject.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
```

I get

```
20170516
```

Okay, alright. (Note: This is a class of the program, not the test!)

Now I run my Unittest (Mockito, JUnit) with `mvn test`. I get an error, which is related to the JSONObject version. And the log says:

```
0.0.20131108.vaadin1
```

I found out, that this version comes from this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I delete it, my test works fine.

But now other tests fail, which uses this dependency

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

and in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I configure maven, that the program uses JSON version 20170516, but spring-test can still use jsonassert?

Even if almost the same name, I don't think this is a duplicate of

- [two versions of dependencies in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406604/two-versions-of-dependencies-in-maven)

-- Edit 1

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep json 
[INFO] +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test 
[INFO] |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test 
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:2.2.0:test 
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test 
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test 
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20170516:compile
```

Comment: "how can I configure maven, that the program uses JSON version 20170516, but spring-test can still use jsonassert" Is maven [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) what you're looking for? You could make certain versions used during tests and other versions using in compiling and building.

Comment: No, that does not help. As I wrote, the critical point where the newer version of JsonObject is used is in the class, not in the test of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `spring-test` or `jsonassert` will shade the `org.json:json` dependency internally in the future version you are stuck having to use one version of `org.json:json` across the classpath.

Not all Java dependencies are compatible, see [classpath hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373193/what-is-classpath-hell-and-is-was-it-really-a-problem-for-java).

You can try defining a [Dependency Exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) for the problematic version but this can potentially brake `jsonassert` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A added this exclusion, but I still get version 0.0.20131108.vaadin1 of JSON in test context.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` and you have to exclude every single one. Do note that it might be a bad idea, the libraries might brake.

Comment: @Paflow updated the answer, exclusion should match the artifact `groupId` and `artifactId`.

Comment: Did the trick. As the usages of JSONAssert are quite clear (all tests which use mockMvc), I think I can take the risk.

Answer (score 5):

you need to add the dependencies that you want to enforce specific version when there is conflict in `dependencyManagement`. This ensures the maven uses 20170516 version of `json` dependency even though `jsonassert` depends different version.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Please see [Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven?rq=1)

or you can use `<exclusions>` to exclude a child dependency.

Comment: I removed the two from <dependecies> and put your code under </dependencies>, but now I get a lot of errors.

Comment: you shouldn't remove the above from `dependencies`. You should keep them and you need to to include them in the `dependencyManagement` as well.